# Copying a file from windows 10 desktop to Azure VM

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, copy

I need to copy a relatively large file (3GB) onto an Azure VM from my local Windows 10 desktop. I believe people using Linux can use `rsync`, but how can I do this from Windows 10?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have network connectivity from your laptop to the Azure VM through a VPN?
If so you can use robocopy or PowerShell to do the copy

Comment: I can SSH into the VM (running Ubuntu 18) from my local Windows 10 Pro desktop, if that is what you are asking. Apologies, but I am not an expert in OS/devOps. I am merely a PHP developer busy learning some new things out of necessity. What command would I use in PowerShell to attempt (1) Connection similar to the way I use PuTTY to SSH into the VM, and (2) to actually copy the file over. Please advise?

Comment: I found an article here: https://www.thomasmaurer.ch/2019/07/copy-files-to-azure-vm-using-powershell-remoting/. I have installed PowerShell 6,and am exploring the possibilities now.

Comment: When following the rest of the instructions, I get this:

New-PSSession : [13.82.xxx.xxx] The background process reported an error with the following message: The SSH client session has ended with error message: subsystem request failed on channel 0.
At line:1 char:6

Normal SSH login works via PuTTY.

Comment: Went further using instructions here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse and https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/ssh-remoting-in-powershell-core?view=powershell-6. When using SSH to connect using PowerShell, connection is successful, but how do I now copy the file over? The instructions on the first link (thomasmaurer in second comment) does not work ($s =  ...).

Comment: Keep getting System error 1067 - "OpenSSH could not be started".  This is after following instructions here as well: https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/wiki/Install-Win32-OpenSSH. Could this be because I do have PowerShell64, and the instructions is Win32? There does not seem to be instructions for Win64... Now I am vcalling it a night. Any insights you have will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: All of the above are fruitless, but turns out I could use WinSCP as you suggested at this question: https://serverfault.com/questions/985179/azure-inbound-rule-order/985198#985198. Please edit this answer to include WinSCP and I will mark it as the accepted answer. Thank you!